# how to fetch specific data from API using RTK Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rtk-query

firstly I am new to RTK Query. I am trying to fetch some specific data from API but I don't understand how to do it. If anyone can help me it will be great.

My API link: https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches

I just need some specific data like **flight_number, mission_name, upcoming, launch_date_utc, rocket_name, launch_success, mission_patch_small** .

I already fetched data but can't able to fetch particular data what I want, don't understand how to do it.

My code:
**App.tsx:**

```
import { useMissionsQuery, useMissionQuery } from "./services/missionsApi";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading, isFetching, isSuccess } = useMissionsQuery();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>SpaceX Launches: Mission</h1>
      {isLoading && <h2>...Loading</h2>}
      {isFetching && <h2>...Fetching</h2>}
      {error && <h2>Something went wrong</h2>}
      {isSuccess && (
        <div>
          {data?.map((mission) => {
            return (
              <div className="data" key={mission.flight_number}>
                <span>{mission.mission_name}</span>
                <span>
                  <MissionDetail flight_number={mission.flight_number} />
                </span>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export const MissionDetail = ({ flight_number }: { flight_number: string }) => {
  const { data } = useMissionQuery(flight_number);
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)}</pre>;
};

export default App;
```

**services/missionsApi.tsx:**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { Mission } from "../models/mission.model";

export const missionsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "missionsApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    missions: builder.query<Mission[], void>({
      query: () => "/",
    }),
    mission: builder.query<Mission, string>({
      query: (flight_number) => `/${flight_number}?`,
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useMissionsQuery, useMissionQuery } = missionsApi;
```

model
**mission.model.ts:**

```
export interface Mission {
  flight_number: string;
  mission_name: string;
  upcoming: string;
  launch_date_utc: string;
  rocket: string;
  rocket_name: string;
  launch_success: string;
  links: string;
  mission_patch_small: string;
}
```

and **store.ts**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { missionsApi } from "./services/missionsApi";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [missionsApi.reducerPath]: missionsApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(missionsApi.middleware),
});
```

Comment: It seems you are exactly doing that - what is not working for you?

Comment: I can not access my api's nested items. If you go to my api links then you will see rocket_name under rocket tag I can not access these kind of items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is the same as @phry -- **you are already doing this correctly**!  You have already fetched all of the data that you need, and you are already displaying individual properties:

```
<span>{mission.mission_name}</span>
```

Keep doing that!

---

Having looked at the API response, you don't actually need to be making any API calls in your `MissionDetail` component.  The list that gets returned from the `useMissionsQuery` in the `App` component is giving lots of data about each mission in the list.

You should create a render component that takes the `Mission` object and displays its information.

```
function MissionDetail({ mission }: { mission: Mission }) {
  return (
    <div className="data">
      <div>Flight Number: {mission.flight_number}</div>
      <div>Name: {mission.mission_name}</div>
      <div>Launch Date: {mission.launch_date_utc}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then your home page can pass each item in the array off to the `MissionDetail` component to render it. You can simplify your loop to this:

```
{data?.map((mission) => (
  <MissionDetail key={mission.flight_number} mission={mission} />
))}
```

(though it seems like `flight_number` is not a unique key)

You might have other places in your app where you want to render a specific mission by its `flight_number`, like on a detail page for a mission.  That would be where you'd want to call `useMissionQuery(flight_number)`.

```
function MissionByFlightNumber({ flight_number }: { flight_number: string }) {
  const { data, isError, isLoading, isSuccess } = useMissionQuery(flight_number);
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <h2>...Loading</h2>}
      {isError && <h2>Something went wrong</h2>}
      {isSuccess && data && <MissionDetail mission={data} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/spacex-api-rtk-query-ijb9ih?file=/src/App.tsx)